# Automatically add the "android" tag to questions migrated to SO

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, migration

I don't know how much work this would be, but it would be nice if questions migrated from here to Stack Overflow were automatically tagged with [android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android).  I generally follow up and retag the SO version after a migration, but I wouldn't expect all users with the VTC privilege to do so.  It might help prevent these questions from getting lost in the shuffle.

Comment: +1 to this because it would be convenient, and I end up approving a lot of your tag edits over on SO. Think of all the SO rep you'd miss out on, though! :P

Comment: @eldarerathis My lack of SO rep is actually kind of hilarious given that I'm a programmer and so active on the network :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many questions of this type are we talking about? How many questions are migrated from here to SO on a daily basis?

This would be a fair amount of work, and I'd need to know that it's because there are 10+ questions of this type. Often for low volume stuff, handling it manually is the best option until the volume increases.

It's also a little tricky since the intrinsic tag on *this* site has to exist on the target site, etc.

Looking here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/away

I see 10 questions going to SO for the month of November.

Comment: I would agree that it might not be worth the effort at this point, more just something to think about.  Perhaps in the future it would be generalizable, with migrations from Music to SO having `music` added for example.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I **guess** the problem is implementing it once. Once it's there and it works, enabling it for every site would be trivial.

Comment: @matthew it's possible for the future, of course, but right now I don't see a pressing problem